# Excel 2013 VBA - ActiveX Cascading ComboBoxes - Issue with having only related values in cmb4

Tags: excel, combobox, activex, cascadingdropdown, vba

What I am trying to achieve is Cascading or Dependent ComboBoxes and with help I have finally had success with all 4.

```
ComboBox1 = Category
ComboBox2 = Sub Category
ComboBox3 = Location (unique to chosen subcategory)
ComboBox4 = Customer (unique to chosen subcategory and location)
```

What is occurring is in comboBox4 all of the customers for the selected Location are populating combobox4 instead of all of the customers for the selected location that also coincide with the subcategory.

```
ComboBox1 = cmbRent
ComboBox2 = cmbSub
ComboBox3 = cmbLoc
ComboBox4 = cmbCust
```

All of my codes which are located on the worksheet "CHART".
   All of my data is located on the worksheet "DATA"
   All of my ComboBoxes are located "CHART"

The data that is being referenced is in 4 columns in the order that the boxes are.

```
Column1 = Category
Column2 = Sub Category
Column3 = Location 
Column4 = Customer
```

I feel like I need to be referenceing the Selection in cmbSub and cmbLoc in order to achieve what I want?

Here are all of my combobox codes that are applied to the worksheet

```
    Private Sub cmbRent_Change()

    Dim wsChart As Worksheet
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim listOfValues As String 'To store list of values already added
    Dim ValueToAdd As String 'To store new value to add
    listOfValues = ""
    Set wsChart = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CHART")
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")


    MyVal = Me.cmbRent.Value

    'loop thru col B
    lr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'clear cmbSub
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CHART").cmbSub.Clear


     For x = 2 To lr
    If MyVal = wsData.Cells(x, 1) Then
       'add to combobox
        ValueToAdd = wsData.Cells(x, 2) 'Get value from worksheet
        If InStr(listOfValues, wsData.Cells(x, 2)) = 0 Then
        'Check to see if the value has already been added
        'If not, add to values added and add the item to the combobox.
              listOfValues = listOfValues & ValueToAdd
              Me.cmbSub.AddItem ValueToAdd
        End If
    End If
    Next x

          ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CHART").cmbSub.ListIndex = -1
    End Sub

        Private Sub cmbSub_Change()

    Dim wsChart As Worksheet
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim listOfValues As String 'To store list of values already added
    Dim ValueToAdd As String 'To store new value to add
    listOfValues = ""
    Set wsChart = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CHART")
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")

    MyVal = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CHART").cmbSub.Value

    'loop thru col c
    lr = wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

          ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CHART").cmbLoc.Clear

    For x = 2 To lr
    If MyVal = wsData.Cells(x, 2) Then
       'add to combobox
        ValueToAdd = wsData.Cells(x, 3) 'Get value from worksheet
        If InStr(listOfValues, wsData.Cells(x, 3)) = 0 Then
        'Check to see if the value has already been added
        'If not, add to values added and add the item to the combobox.
              listOfValues = listOfValues & ValueToAdd
              ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CHART").cmbLoc.AddItem ValueToAdd
        End If
    End If
    Next x

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CHART").cmbLoc.ListIndex = -1


      End Sub


      Private Sub cmbLoc_Change()

    Dim wsChart As Worksheet
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim listOfValues As String 'To store list of values already added
    Dim ValueToAdd As String 'To store new value to add
    listOfValues = ""
    Set wsChart = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CHART")
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")

    MyVal = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CHART").cmbLoc.Value

    'loop thru col D
    lr = wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

          ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CHART").cmbCust.Clear

    For x = 2 To lr
    If MyVal = wsData.Cells(x, 3) Then
       'add to combobox
        ValueToAdd = wsData.Cells(x, 4) 'Get value from worksheet
        If InStr(listOfValues, wsData.Cells(x, 4)) = 0 Then
        'Check to see if the value has already been added
        'If not, add to values added and add the item to the combobox.
              listOfValues = listOfValues & ValueToAdd
              ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CHART").cmbCust.AddItem ValueToAdd
        End If
    End If
     Next x

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CHART").cmbCust.ListIndex = -1


    End Sub
```

If you would like some more background, please view this link: [Excel '13 VBA Cascading ComboBox - Trouble getting unique values in Combobox2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31859476/excel-13-vba-cascading-combobox-trouble-getting-unique-values-in-combobox2/31859986?noredirect=1#comment51640496_31859986)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't doing a comparison for the subcategory in your code.

A bigger issue that you are having is that you don't seem to understand what the code is doing.  I would take some time to walk through your code and try to understand what every line is doing.  Possibly watch the video that you referenced in one of your other posts again.

The part of your code that is checking which values to put into combobox4, aka cmbCust is here:

```
If MyVal = wsData.Cells(x, 3) Then
```

This is checking MyVal, which has previously been defined as:

```
MyVal = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CHART").cmbLoc.Value
```

This is only the selection in the cmbLoc, which corresponds to the location, but doesn't include the subcategory.

You need to do two checks, and I'd fix the variable names so that they are more clear.

```
Dim LocVal As String
Dim SubCatVal As String

....more code here

LocVal = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CHART").cmbLoc.Value
SubCatVal = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CHART").cmbSub.Value

....more code here


'Now do the comparison
If LocVal = wsData.Cells(x, 3) And SubCatVal = wsData.Cells(x,2) Then
    ValueToAdd = wsData.Cells(x, 4) 

.....Rest of code in the if statement
```

Comment: First of all , Thank you for your response again. I do however understand what each line is doing, I just dont fully understand how to make them do it with out help of others..

    I have played around with changing up the parts that you mentions such as changing what myVal references but put everything back to how I first had it in order to post here.     

as I mentioned in my original post, I feel that I am needing to reference the both the subcategory and location. 

I really do appreciate your help!

Comment: And by the way, You are a BEAUTIFUL man, It worked!!   I have been working on this off and on while trying to learn as I go for almost 1.5months now.   On to the next part of the project!

Comment: Wasn't trying to be judgmental....I was just trying to make suggestions that might help you learn so that you'd be able to edit things in the future.  I did notice your comment about what you thought you needed, but there were no comments stating what you had tried and which lines you needed help with.  I'm happy to help, as I know not everyone has experience, and I've seen CS majors with similar problems, and was just trying to offer some advice.

Comment: Tone is not the easiest to convey over text! I really do appreciate it.